# Get first empty row of sheet in Excel file with Python

Tags: python, excel, algorithm, openpyxl, worksheet

I need to find the first empty row in an Excel file, i am currently using Openpyxl with Python.
I couldn't find any method that does what i need so i am trying to make my own. This is my code:

```
 book = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
 ws = book.worksheets[0]
 for row in ws['C{}:C{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)]:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is None:
            print cell.value
            break
```

I am iterating through all cells in the "C" column and i am "breaking" if the cell is empty. The problem is that it won't break, it'll just keep print out "None" values.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry doesn't work, it just won't print out anything. I tried to Print its position but it just won't work.

Comment: With your `break` you will only quit the inner loop `for cell in row:`.

Comment: Well i think that this is correct, my outer loop itìs just one column..if i quit my inner loop then i am out of the whole thing

Comment: No, your outer loop will supply the next row.

Comment: oh, Thanks. Any suggestion for a solution?

Comment: Found a solution:                                                  
    `for cell in ws['C']:
    if cell.value == None:
        print cell.row
        break`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way your loop will stop if it encounters any empty cell in a row.
If you want the row wo be completely empty you can use `all`.

```
book = load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
ws = book.worksheets[0]
for cell in ws["C"]:
    if cell.value is None:
        print cell.row
        break
else:
    print cell.row + 1
```

Update to the question in the comments:

`ws["C"]` will get a slice from `C1:CX` where `X` is the last filled cell in any column. So if the `C` column happens to be the longest column and every entry is filled you will only get cells with `cell is not None` so you won't break out of the loop. If you didn't break out of the loop you will enter the `else` block and since you looped till the last filled row, the first empty row will be the next one.

Comment: Thanks, how can i print the row number that is empty?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: That works perfectly thanks a lot!! May i ask you a little exaplanation to understand what's going on? What does the "row" vector stores? I don't get the row[0].row. Thanks

Comment: The row vector stores a tuple of cells. In your case this is just one cell per row. So `row[0]` -> access the cell `.row` access the row property. By the way your solution in the comments is cleaner than this one.

Comment: I changed it to a better version.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Why using `print cell.row + 1`?

Answer (score 9):

There is a built-in worksheet property "max_row" in openpyxl:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_row
max_row: an integer defining the maximum row index containing data

Comment: It looks like `ws.max_row` is used in the question. How are you suggesting that it should be used differently? Did you see the comment about changing `is` to `==` that was left by the question asker?

Comment: @JasonAller I didn't notice the original post's use of ws.max_row, but it seems to explain why the original post's code didn't work.  In combination with ws.min_row (the minimium row index containing data), the original post's code performs "in the range of rows known to contain data, what's the first row without data" so the answer will be None.  To the original goal "find the first empty row in an Excel file", the answer is ws.max_row+1.  No need for for loops and if statements.

Comment: This is the better answer. If you have two columns A and B both filled to A20 and B20, but A3 is empty, the first solution will find A3 as first empty row and this solution will find row 20 as the last filled row.